# MTM, automated tests, specify a location for the assemblies

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager

We are working with TFS + MTM to run some automation.
We have succesfully created Test Plan, Test Suite and Automated Test Cases. If we run them from MTM everything is fine but there is one issue regarding the drop location.

Right now, MTM picks the assemblies from \TFS\MyBuildDefinition\bin automatically while in our drop location we have a different structure so sometimes MTM can't find the test assembly.
If I configure an automated test there isn't much to play around with so I was wondering how can I specify a custom location for the assemblies that need to be tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify additional files that are located in specific folders and should be deployed before running automated tests using *Test Settings*:

[image]